# Android Bluetooth Printer Suggestion

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I want to print user filled data on Bluetooth printer using android. Problem what i am facing that i feel problem in placing text and image as it is in the image. I do not want that first i store data on external file then i pick that pdf to be printed. Is there any direct way???
please give me suggestions... Please have a look on image that i have attached..
I have used this example:   [How to print image and some data from an android device, using printer (print via bluetooth)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15540614/how-to-print-image-and-some-data-from-an-android-device-using-printer-print-vi)[image]